# SQL Update with where clause with variables from VS2010 Winforms

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do an update query from a winform with two variables without using a dataset.
I assign both of my variable and then run the query but it keeps giving the error that zcomp is not a valid column name.  Which of course is true but I tell it which column before I say = zcomp.  Below is my code that is running the query.

```
Dim zamnt As Integer = WopartsDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
Dim zcomp As Integer = gridRow.Cells(0).Value

Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MNT-MGR-2\SQLEX;Initial Catalog=MT;Integrated Security=True"
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.sparts SET [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] = [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] - zamnt WHERE [ComponentID] = zcomp"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show("Error while updating record on table..." & ex.Message, "Update Records")
Finally
  con.Close()
  gridRow.Cells(4).Value = "Yes"
End Try
```

I have tried it several different ways.  It works just fine if I take out the zamnt and zcomp and put the actual number values that are in the variables.  Please help I've been searching all day for a way to use the variables with this update query.
Thanks,
Stacy

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for how to use parameters in ADO.NET. For your example, it can look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@zamnt", zamnt);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@zcomp", zcomp);
```

Put these two lines anywhere before `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Because parameters need a `@` prefix, you would also need to change your query to say `@zamnt` instead of just `zamnt`, and same for `zcomp`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.sparts SET [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] = [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] - @zamnt WHERE [ComponentID] = @zcomp"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using parameters, the "Using" statement closes the connection and disposes resources:

```
    Dim zamnt As Integer = WopartsDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
    Dim zcomp As Integer = gridRow.Cells(0).Value

    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MNT-MGR-2\SQLEX;Initial Catalog=MT;Integrated Security=True")
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.sparts SET [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] = [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] - @zamnt WHERE [ComponentID] = @zcomp"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zamt", zamnt)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zcomp", zcomp)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while updating record on table..." & ex.Message, "Update Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
        gridRow.Cells(4).Value = "Yes"
    End Try
```

Comment: Not a fan of AddWithValue(). It has some type-related gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried this?

```
Dim zamnt As Integer = WopartsDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
Dim zcomp As Integer = gridRow.Cells(0).Value

Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MNT-MGR-2\SQLEX;Initial Catalog=MT;Integrated Security=True"
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.sparts SET [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] = [dbo.sparts.QtyonHand] -" + zamnt + " WHERE [ComponentID] =" + zcomp
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show("Error while updating record on table..." & ex.Message, "Update Records")
Finally
  con.Close()
  gridRow.Cells(4).Value = "Yes"
End Try
```